# Select value inside object

Tags: javascript

How can I get the `second` value from `videoid:uoSDF234`and make it countdown ?

1. first I need `"videoid":"uoSDF234"` be the first countdown  then next will be `"videoid":"0apq3ss"` and so on (if I add more data).
2. when I click the stop button, `label id="vstopresult"` will show the stopped `videoid` and `second`.
3. the countdown will looping for each `videoid` in `videolist`.

```js
var videoinfo = [{"startdatetime":"2014-12-21 00:23:14","totalsecondrun":"2019402310","videolist":
[{"videoid":"uoSDF234","second":"10"},{"videoid":"0apq3ss","second":"14"}]}]; 
// JavaScript Document

var calduration = function(){
  $.each(videoinfo, function(i, obj) {
   $("#vstart").append(obj.startdatetime);
   $("#vtotoals").append(obj.totalsecondrun);
   
   $("#vid").append(videoinfo[0].videolist[0].videoid);
   $("#vlefts").append(videoinfo[0].videolist[0].second);

     var output = $("#vlefts");
     var isPaused = false;
     var time = videoinfo[0].videolist[0].second;
     var t = window.setInterval(function() {
      if(!isPaused) {
       time--;
       output.text(time);
      }
      if (time == 0){
       clearInterval(t);
      }
     }, 1000);
     
     //with jquery
     $("#vpause").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      isPaused = true;
     });
     
     $("#vplay").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      isPaused = false;
     });
     
     $("#vstop").on('click', function(e) {
      clearInterval(t);
      $("#vstopresult").append(time);
     });
    
  });
               

};
  
  
calduration();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
         <label id="vstart"></label><br>
         <label id="vtotoals"></label><br>
            <label id="vid"></label><br>
            <label id="vlefts"></label><br>
            <input type="button" value="play" id="vplay"/>
            <input type="button" value="pause" id="vpause"/>
            <input type="button" value="stop" id="vstop"/><br>
            <label id="vstopresult"></label>
        </div>
```

Comment: So what is your expected output? What does this algorithm do? Be more specific

Comment: @VincentBeltman I have updated the real expected I want.

Comment: @VincentBeltman my expected output is when I stop it show me the `videoid` and `second` , for this something like player, I have updated question what really I need

Comment: To get the `second` value of `videoid:uoSDF234`, the reference would be `videoinfo[0].videolist[0].second`.

Comment: Did I correctly interpret your question in that you want videoid `0apq3ss` to be displayed **after** the `192312` seconds of videoid `uoSDF234` have elapsed? Because right now you walk through all the entries of `"videolists"` with `$.each` without waiting for one video to end before you go to the next. If I run the code without the `var timer=[..]` part I get both videoid's immediately.

Comment: @Xotic750 do you have any idea how to continue countdown to the next `videoid` and `second` ? example when `videoid:uoSDF234` `second is 0`, `"videoid":"0apq3ss"` will continue countdown

Comment: @funkwurm hi, I agree with your first question. Now I updated my code, first run is `uoSDF234` , but how to make it auto change to next `videoid` and `second` when `uoSDF234`(first video) is count to 0 ?

Comment: Yes. Like @funkwurm said, you need to wait for the first countdown to finish before moving onto the next. Right now you start the first and then immediately go to the second without waiting for the first timer to complete. So you need to rethink your method.

Comment: @Xotic750 I not say immediately go to the second, I have mention when the first is count to 0.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are. You get the first lot of data and you create your counters and update the DOM, then you immediately go to the second data and create your counters and then you overwrite the DOM with the new information. Don't believe me, put an `alert` in as the first line of your `each` function.

Comment: When @Xotic750 says "you [..] immediately go to the second", he means that's what the code is doing right now, and the reason of that is that you're using `$.each` to go through all the entries of `"videolist"`. What you wanna do is only look at `.videolist[0]`, do what it needs to do, setInterval, etc. and when that is all done, then go to `.videolist[1]`.

Comment: @funkwurm I agree what you said, but I only know `$.each` to read json data , by the way i updated my code

Answer (score 1):

One crude possibility is to use `setInterval`, an example may be.

```js
var videoinfo = [{
        "startdatetime": "2014-12-21 00:23:14",
        "totalsecondrun": "2019402310",
        "videolist": [{
            "videoid": "uoSDF234",
            "second": "10"
        }, {
            "videoid": "0apq3ss",
            "second": "14"
        }]
    }],
    index = 0,
    timerEl = document.getElementById('timer'),
    countDown = 0,
    intervalId;

function startCountdown() {
    if (index < videoinfo[0].videolist.length) {
        countDown = videoinfo[0].videolist[index].second;
        intervalId = setInterval(function () {
            timerEl.textContent = countDown;
            if (countDown < 1) {
                clearInterval(intervalId);
                index += 1;
                setTimeout(function () {
                    startCountdown();
                }, 1000);
            } else {
                countDown -= 1;
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
}

startCountdown();
```

```html
<div id='timer'></div>
```

Comment: I have use `setInterval`

Comment: I have see each number have countdown once, but in mycode , second is json , so how to countdown each one continuously?

Comment: You have an `array`, just like I have in my example and the property `second` of each item (an `object`) has a number value.

Comment: can you try to mix my json ? sorry because I still very new in jquery hard to understand

Comment: I haven't used any jQuery (which is just a library of functions written in javascript with a focus on cross browser DOM manipulation) and it seems you need to go and read about javascript. In particular [`array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) and [`object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object). Your [`JSON`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) (an open standard format that uses human-readable text to transmit data objects) has beed parsed and is now just arrays and objects.

Comment: There is plenty of reading here on SO and out there on the internet, but you can try reading this as a start. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68382/discussion-between-im-happy-and-xotic750).

Comment: I have an idea , how to turn videoid value and second value to 2 array? then I can use your method example ... I try to change it to array but failed [click here for js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkqLk55a/)

Comment: when the last index is countdown finish can return to index 0 again ?

Comment: You can do that very simply.